# Parsing output of wsl --list --verbose in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Aim: Offer docker-desktop feature of showing status of wsl (stopped/running). In Docker Desktop this can be seen in the left bottom corner.

Consequence: Parse output of wsl --list --verbose

Current implementation in main.ts of electron app:

```js
ipcMain.on('cmd', async (event, arg)=>{
  const execute = (command, callback)=>{
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      callback(stdout);
    });
  };

// call the function
  execute('wsl --list --verbose', (output) => {
    event.sender.send('cmd-callback',output)
  });
})
```

Problem: [image: Image of output in regexr.com]

Current attempt:  `console.log(args.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String))`

Current result:

```
[
    " \u0000 \u0000N\u0000A\u0000M\u0000E\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000S\u0000T\u0000A\u0000T\u0000E\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000V\u0000E\u0000R\u0000S\u0000I\u0000O\u0000N\u0000",
    "\u0000",
    "\u0000*\u0000 \u0000U\u0000b\u0000u\u0000n\u0000t\u0000u\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000S\u0000t\u0000o\u0000p\u0000p\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u00002\u0000",
    "\u0000",
    "\u0000 \u0000 \u0000d\u0000o\u0000c\u0000k\u0000e\u0000r\u0000-\u0000d\u0000e\u0000s\u0000k\u0000t\u0000o\u0000p\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000S\u0000t\u0000o\u0000p\u0000p\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u00002\u0000",
    "\u0000",
    "\u0000 \u0000 \u0000d\u0000o\u0000c\u0000k\u0000e\u0000r\u0000-\u0000d\u0000e\u0000s\u0000k\u0000t\u0000o\u0000p\u0000-\u0000d\u0000a\u0000t\u0000a\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000S\u0000t\u0000o\u0000p\u0000p\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u00002\u0000",
    "\u0000",
    "\u0000"
]
```

Required output as a JavaScript Array [string[]]:

```
[
  ['Ubuntu', 'Stopped', '2'],
  ['docker-desktop', 'Stopped', '2'],
  ['docker-desktop-data', 'Stopped', '2'],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more mappings and filter you can get close to the requested output.

```js
currentResult
  .map(v => v.replace(/\u0000/g,'')) // remove all \u0000
  .map(v => { // remove all double spaces
    while (v.replace(/\s\s/g,' ') != v)
      v = v.replace(/\s\s/g,' ').trim();
    return v;
  })
  .filter(v => v) // remove empty lines
  .map(v => v.split(' ')); // split by space
```